# Is there any way to see version of libraries (classes) included in a .dex file

Tags: android, apk, dex

When I analyse a .dex file (i.e. using ClassyShark) from an Android app, I see a certain library, for example com.google.firebase (or any other package included). Is there any way to see what version of this package included in this .dex file? Just like, what version of the library is used in the .pom file if it would be a Maven project.
Thanks

Comment: Are you want to see the details of classes that wrapped in .dex file?

Comment: Just the version number of the classes would be sufficient, but yes I want to see the details.

Comment: use JadX (https://github.com/skylot/jadx). in JadX GUI, you can find under Resources folder. You cant get all library versions. But play service, firebase versions and all are visible.

Comment: There is resources.arsc file but this can't be opened in JadX GUI. There is no Resources folder anywhere. Where am I supposed to see the Resources folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no. There is no information about the version of the library stored in the apk/dex/resources.arsc. Although it's possible the library itself has a static constant somewhere with its own version.

In order to figure out the version of the library, you would have to compare the actual bytecode of the library with that from known versions of the library.

Comment: Thanks, even though the answer is no.